# Failing to program Cyclone IV GX device via JTAG

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, cyclone

I just got the aforementioned device and, upon writing a simple program (it compiles) and going into Programmer, when I try to program the device with the .sof file, I see is `(Failed)` and Quartus' Messages says

`Error (209031): Device chain in Chain Description File does not match physical device chain -- expected 1 device(s) but found 2 device(s).`

Furthermore, when I try to use the Board Test System that comes with the kit, I get

`Java.lang.Exception: No USB Blaster detected.`

even though I know 100% that I have the USB blaster driver installed, and have been using it with a different Cyclone II board.

I suspect there might be some sort of mismatch between the version of Quartus I have (13sp1) and the version of Quartus indicated by the development kit that comes with my device (12.1) but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Have you updated the firmware on the usb blaster? Quartus stinks, its buggy, sometimes you have to push a few buttons to get it to recognize

Comment: Look int Quartus *Messages* window - what is the error being displayed? Did you select USB Blaster in the device list to be used for programming? I do not think it is software version issue, if your version supports the device it should work with it OK (e.g. ver 14 does not support Cyclone 3 - and this device just does not appear in the list).

Comment: @Anonymous added the message

Comment: You have two devices in your chain description, probably because in the programmer you've both asked it to detect the chain, and then loaded in a SOF which describes a device.  Clear out the programmer and just load the SOF and try again.

Comment: Cool, now you can use Google and search for answer, for example http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-49407.html

Comment: I have had the similar problem, I noticed the device number was I selected, was similar but wrong, after fixing this issue, the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the fact that, in order to program the Cyclone, the Programmer needs *all* devices in the device list and it turns out there is a secondary Max II device that needs to be there as well. I did an Auto-Detect, removed the duplicate Cyclone, and everything worked find from then on.